# How to rule out the secondary NIC's from nmap

Tags: nmap

When I do a network scan I get series of live hosts .

host1 - 192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3,192.168.1.4
host2 - 192.168.1.5,192.168.1.6,192.168.1.7
host3 - 192.168.1.8,192.168.1.9,192.168.1.10

But the thing is , Each host has around 3 Nic's assigned to it so it has 3 Ip's for same host . 2 are secondary and 1 is primary. How to rule out the secondary Nic's ?

As far as I saw I couldn't find any options or I don't know whether there is a option like that .. If someone could confirm it , it would be helpful.

Comment: How can you identify which NIC is primary and which are secondary from the outside? Are there specific ports open on primary ones which are closed on secondary ones, for example?

Comment: Sadly no . ports are commonly open , example 443 is open for all the IP's in each host. I checked it already.

Comment: If there isn't a method to tell them apart externally, there isn't going to be a method to avoid scanning some subset of them, other than manually excluding them from the scan. nmap doesn't know that a given NIC is on the same host as another one.

Comment: I just wanted to know that method to tell them apart ..

Comment: Would it help to know which addresses belong to the same host, even if you can't identify which one is "primary"? There's an NSE script for that: https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/duplicates.html

Comment: @bonsaiviking  thanks , but I have already filtered em out using ssl-cert .. the hard thing is finding the primary ..

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a network scan it means you are trying to find all the IPs that are 'alive' on that network, so, if if every host has three IPs listening on that subnet inevitably you will get all of them to respond.

I don't think what you want if possible. The only thing I can think of it's that the lowest IP should be the primary on each host. Not guaranteed, but very likely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. unluckily the lowest IP is not the primary in real scenario . They are totally not in order.